# Radio Button Checked Effect Single Outside Element

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

Just a quick question can a CSS radio button effect something outside the element it's in.

For example:

```
<div class="radio">
      <input id="radio-green" type="radio" name="radio-b"/>
      <label for="radio-green">Green</label>

      <input id="radio-blue" type="radio" name="radio-b" checked />
      <label for="radio-blue">Blue</label>

      <input id="radio-yellow" type="radio" name="radio-b"/>
      <label for="radio-yellow">Yellow</label>

      <input id="radio-red" type="radio" name="radio-b"/>
      <label for="radio-red">Red</label>

      <input id="radio-white" type="radio" name="radio-b"/>
      <label for="radio-white">White</label>
</div>

<div class="square"></div>
```

With the CSS something like this?

```
.square {
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin:0 auto;
background:red;
}
input#radio-green:checked .square {background:green;}
```

Or would I need to use JS?

Here's a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they weren't inside their parent `<div>` you could do it, because they'd be siblings.  Unfortunately CSS rules don't let you traverse back up the tree.

If you took them out the `<div class="radio">` then you could use the `~` sibling combinator:

```
#radio-green:checked ~ .square {background:green;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/1/)**

Otherwise, I'd probably use JS to add a class to the `<div class="radio>` when each radio was clicked and then style the square accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know jQuery, you can use:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.square').css('background', $(this).next().text());
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/3/)**

Comment: How would I do for example when the green is unchecked the box get's an outline?

Comment: that only makes it when it's checked, how to check if the radio is unchecked with? here's a fiddle (not working) http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/5/

Comment: You need `$('input[type=radio]')` instead of `input[type=radio]:eq(0)` and better using `change` instead of `click` event for your input http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/6/

Comment: Hey sorry, last thing. How about adding a class instead of css? It doesn't seem to work? http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/7/

Comment: You're missing `outline` in your CSS. You want this: http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/10/

Comment: Thanks, Ok sorry again. What about toggle different classes for each radio? http://jsfiddle.net/m8fxw/11/ It works at first, but doesn't seem to toggle once you start clicking on others. :(